# How to import lua file to execute it?

Tags: lua

I'm using Lua Mac 5.1.4 Compiler.

I'm trying to import lua file and run it.

I tried using this code:

```
% lua hello.lua
```

But I'm getting this error:   `stdin:1: unexpected symbol near '%'`

Am I doing something wrong? This is my first day using lua so be easy on me.

Thank you.

Comment: Just a guess since I'm not a Mac person, but did you try without the `%`?

Comment: Yes and I still getting error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that you saw this verbatim text in a tutorial:

```
% lua hello.lua
```

The '%' at the beginning of the line is not something you are supposed to type into your terminal, but is rather a generic prompt indicator.  Sometimes you might see it written as '$' instead:

```
$ lua hello.lua
```

In either case, the first character is not something you type, but rather is a typographical convention to suggest that what follows is to be typed at a prompt.  Your actual prompt might look something like this:

```
mo@macbook$
```

So you would type `lua hello.lua` but your screen would look like this:

```
mo@macbook$ lua hello.lua
```

So, try just entering `lua hello.lua` and see what happens.

Note that the error message you got regarding `stdin:1` is likely from your shell (e.g. bash), and not from Lua (which never even started running due to the malformed command in the shell).

Comment: Thank you. I tried what you said and I still get an error.  `ogramming\ Resources/Lua\ Files/lua ; exit;
Lua 5.2.0 (alpha)  Copyright (C) 1994-2010 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> lua hello.lua
stdin:1: '=' expected near 'hello'
> `
I'm hundred percent sure I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Oh wow.  Yeah, see jpjacob's answer for a solution to this problem.  You're typing into the Lua interpreter commands which are meant to be typed into the terminal directly.

Answer (score 1):

The error `stdin:1: unexpected symbol near '%'` suggests that you typed in `% lua hello.lua` while in an interactive lua session (or you executed a script containing it). Now that's something that you should type in in the commandline window.

Instead try something like `print'Hello World!'`

Answer (score 0):

Lua provides two ways to call a file. One is the loadfile() and the other is the dofile() commands. Try using dofile("hello.lua").That should work.If it doesn't type the absolute path...:)